# How can i push an array onto another if element doesnt exist AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 arrays

```
 $scope.allnamesList =[];
 $scope.namesList = result.data.namesfields;
```

The problem is that i cant clear the allnamesList because i want to preserve values on client side.

I have tried $scope.allnamesList.push.apply($scope.allnamesList, $scope.namesList), but the issue is that it keeps adding even if the values returned from MVC in the result.data.namesfields are already present in $scope.allnamesList.

Is it possible to do a push of elements in nameslist if they dont already exist in allnamesList ?

Comment: you can use a set to avoid duplicates if the individual elements in the names list are just strings

Comment: Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an array

Comment: the list is a list of objects. Also Set can't be implicitly converted to an array type?

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects

Comment: The issue here is that it is a list of objects and one property is boolean and the list is bound to a grid which governs if a checkbox is selected or not . If i use the suggested link  the state of the check box is not saved . When it filters it seems to filter even if i check for the stae of the checkbox